# Linux Apache Server Running Phusion Passenger and 2 Apps has 8 ruby processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I'm trying to resolve some memory issues on my Linux (Ubuntu) Apache server which runs Phusion Passenger and 2 Rails apps successfully.

Everytime I kill all the ruby processes or restart the server, I keep getting 8 Ruby processes running all using 10% (100mb) of my system's RAM.

When I disable one of the apps, my processes go down to 7, and if I disable all my apps, I get 6 processes...

Surly I shouldn't be getting so many processes from running two applications... or even 0 applications?

Am I missing something, is this normal?

Heres a screenshot of my processes when all apps are running... the PPID is the parent process... (3396 is PassengerHelper) 
[image: Heres a screenshot of my processes when all apps are running... the PPID is the parent process...]

Comment: Depends entirely on how you've configured passenger - there are a lot of settings that affect this (pool sizes, min pool sizes, spawn settings etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Frederick Cheung, I did some research: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize

> 8.6.1. PassengerMaxPoolSize
>
> The maximum number of application processes that may simultaneously
>   exist. A larger number results in higher memory usage, but improves
>   the ability to handle concurrent HTTP requests. The optimal value
>   depends on your system’s hardware and your workload. You can learn
>   more at the Phusion article Tuning Phusion Passenger’s concurrency
>   settings.
>
> If you find that your server is running out of memory then you should
>   lower this value.
>
> This option may only occur once, in the global server configuration.
>   The default value is 6.

I set PassengerMaxPoolSize to 2 in all my virtual host files, and resolved the issue!